# Code for Screen Capture any screen of Android

Tags: android, screen, screenshot, capture, chroot

I am looking for the code which will be able to take screen shot of the any android screen.. I have a device running in rooted mode.. I searched on net.. but all I get informaiton is that it requires rooted access.. thats it.. I am unable to get enough information on how to go further.. if anyone can post a code or link which gives me information how I can take screen show programatically.. I have Android device with root access.

Thank you.

Comment: Try this:http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/

Comment: @Mudit: dont want to use ASL, because ASL requires device to be connected to developer machine, am looking for code which requires rooted access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code,
But this will be bit slow...
I hope you arent trying to make video out of these ;)

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/screencap -p " + path + ”/file.png ”);
```